# Problems referencing subfigures in wrapfigure environment

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats, wrapfigure

I have just tried using wrapfigure (to wrap text around my figure, duh). Now I find that I'm unable to reference my subfigures.

Here's my MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfig}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./Figurer/}}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
    \vspace{-30pt}
    \begin{center}
        \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{test}}\label{label1}

        \quad

        \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{test}}\label{label2}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{-10pt}
    \caption{nice caption}\label{label3}
\end{wrapfigure}


My attempt at referencing figure \ref{label1}

And also figure \ref{label2}.

I had hoped for something like "figure 1A" and "figure 1B"

But the overall figure \ref{label3} seems to work. 

\end{document}
```

And here's a nice picture of my result to go with it.

[image]

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\sidesubfloat` command requires the `\label` command within the mandatory argument, i.e. together with the content to be displayed (the `\includegraphics` command here).

I won't change the manual `\vspace{-30pt}` settings from the O.P. here...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfig}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./Figurer/}}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
    \vspace{-30pt}
    \begin{center}
      \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{ente}\label{label1}}
      \quad
      \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{ente}\label{label2}}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{-10pt}
    \caption{nice caption}\label{label3}
\end{wrapfigure}


My attempt at referencing figure \ref{label1}

And also figure \ref{label2}.

I had hoped for something like "figure 1A" and "figure 1B"

But the overall figure \ref{label3} seems to work. 

\end{document}
```

[image]